# How can the decimal expansion of this rational number not be periodic?

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I just noticed that dividing $1 \div 998$ gives me the apparently non-periodic

$$0.001002004008016032064\ldots ,$$

which is $$10^{-3} + 2\times 10^{-6} + 4\times10^{-9} + 8\times 10^{-12} + \cdots = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i 10^{-3(i+1)}.$$

Since every rational number expands into a finite or periodic decimal expansion, does that become periodic somehow? If so, how?

Comment: The exponent of 2 pattern is followed only in the first few sets of three. [Here is Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F998&dataset=) for the complete expansion with period $498$.

Comment: The fact that the period is long for this number is an artifact of our use of base 10. Any number which is periodic in base 997 or 998 will be in base 10 as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does repeat, but with a very long period: Factoring the denominator into primes gives
$$998 = 2 \cdot \color{#3f3fff}{499};$$
[since $2$ is a factor of $10$ and $10$ is a primitive root modulo $\color{#3f3fff}{499}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Reciprocals_of_integers_not_co-prime_to_10), the period of repetition is $\color{#3f3fff}{499} - 1 = 498$ digits long. Indeed, [consulting WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F998) gives:

$$\color{#bf0000}{
\begin{align}
\smash{\textstyle\frac{1}{998}} =
0.&0\overline{0100200400801603206412825651302605210420841683366733466}\\
&\overline{93386773547094188376753507014028056112224448897795591182}\\
&\overline{36472945891783567134268537074148296593186372745490981963}\\
&\overline{92785571142284569138276553106212424849699398797595190380}\\
&\overline{76152304609218436873747494989979959919839679358717434869}\\
&\overline{73947895791583166332665330661322645290581162324649298597}\\
&\overline{19438877755511022044088176352705410821643286573146292585}\\
&\overline{17034068136272545090180360721442885771543086172344689378}\\
&\overline{757515030060120240480961923847695390781563126252505}.
\end{align}
}$$

A more manageable example of this phenomenon is the repetition of the decimal digits of, e.g., $\frac{1}{14}$: Since $14 = 2 \cdot 7$ and $10$ is a primitive root modulo $7$, the period of the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{14}$ is $7 - 1 = 6$: $\frac{1}{14} = 0.0\overline{714285}$.

Comment: In my mobile the display is a terrible mess.

Comment: @Vim Thanks. In a desktop browser it's a mess too, albeit formatted a little more nicely. Does your mobile browser have problems with the align environment in other display equations, or just with this one?

Comment: No I'm using app instead of a browser.  The app seems to be not very compatible with TeX display, occasionally.

Comment: Especially when the contents are very long ones so as to go over the edge of the screen, the overflowed contents will be lost.  But that won't happen on a PC device.

Comment: @Vim Ah, I see. I manually inserted line breaks in the display (but after <60 characters), so I'm surprised there's an overflow issue. But there's not much content to the equation anyway, it's simply the (long) repeating part of the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{998}$.

Comment: Where does the $499-1$ expression come from? The pattern doesn't hold for all primes; for example, $1/22$ has period $2$.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, you're right. Cheers for pointing this out, and I've edited the post to clarify: For a prime, the period is the order of $10$ modulo $p$. By Fermat's Little Theorem this quantity always divides $p - 1$; if it is equal to $p - 1$, we call $10$ a *primitive root (modulo $p$)*. In your example, we have $10 \neq 1 \bmod 11$ but $10^{\color{red}{2}} = 1 \bmod 11$, giving the period ${\color{red}{2}}$.

Comment: You could start your overline with the zero before the decimal point and then end at the $5$.  That would make it more conspicuous that there are three consecutive zeros at that point.

Comment: Also the first zero in the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{998}$ doesn't repeat.

Comment: @Gimbrint Thanks for point the issue out. I've fixed it, as well as another small error.

Answer (score 8):

Emphasis on "apparently".  The same thing happens with $1/7$: $$\begin{array}{crrrrrrrrrl} & 0 & . & 14 \\
+ & & & & 28 & & & & & & =2\times 14 \\
+ & & & & &  56 & & & & & = 4\times 14 \\
+ & & & & & 1 & 12 & & & & =8\times 14 \\
+ & & & & & & 2 & 24 & & & =16\times 14 \\
+ & & & & & & & 4 & 48 & & = 32\times 14 \\
+ & & & & & & & & & & \cdots \cdots \cdots \\
= & 0 & . & 14 & 28 & 57 & 14 & 28 & \cdots & & \cdots\cdots\cdots \end{array}$$

and $14\ 28\ 57$ keeps repeating, although the pattern identified above also continues.